# Solr 5.1.0: How to set the unique key via Schema API

Tags: solr, schema, unique-key

**In Solr 5.1.0, is it possible to set the unique key via the REST schema api?**
I created a collection with the data driven schema.
Solr would guess what the field type and create the field based on the data I upload.
I can still define fields beforehand by sending a POST request like
*curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary 
'{
"add-field":{"name":"ID","type":"strings","stored":true }}' host:port/solr/test/schema*
But I wonder if there is a way to define it as the unique key.
Tried to add "uniqueKey":true but it failed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No its not possible as of now. Its an open feature request. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7242